# INNER JOIN based on another field AS400

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I am maintaining an old system where the structure and the design of the tables are not created correctly. I know this is an "ugly" situation but I need to deal with it.

I have a table TABLEA containing multiple fields. Two of them represents the MODEL (MODEL1 and MODEL2). Based on status (STATUS), MODEL1 and MODEL2 have the following values:

1. STATUS = "A" THEN MODEL1="the model" AND MODEL2=""
2. STATUS <> "A" THEN MODEL1="" AND MODEL2="the model"

I need to perform a query where I am joining TABLEA with another table TABLEB on the model. According to the status, I need to join the tables with the non-empty model field.

I could resolve it by concatenating MODEL1 and MODEL2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLEA A INNER JOIN TABLEB B
ON (A.MODEL1 || A.MODEL2) = B.MODEL;
```

but I am wondering if there is an elegant way to do it using an IF condition.
Any other solution is welcome.

**UPDATE - SAMPLE DATA**
[image]

Comment: Please show sample table data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, please see my update

Answer (score 1):

You could use union all like this:

```
select * 
  from tablea a
    inner join tableb b
      on a.model1 = b.model and a.status = 'A'
union all
select * 
  from tablea a
    inner join tableb b
      on a.model2 = b.model and a.status <> 'A'
```

Comment: I like this solution very much, but I don't much see the need to check status, as it is implied by being empty or not. If there are no matching empty values, it's clearly unneeded. If there can be, then checking status = A may perform better, but  turning empties into nulls

Comment: Sorry, I was saying, turning empties into nulls may perform better than status <> 'A'

Comment: Over time, changes to the status may leave orphaned models in either of the model fields. Checking status will prevent those orphans from causing problems. Or the user can programmatically ensure data integrity by emptying the appropriate model field when the status changes.

Answer (score 0):

I like jmarkmurphy's solution better, but here is another option, by using left joins.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN b1.col1 = '' THEN b2.col1 ELSE b1.col1 END ......
FROM tablea a
LEFT JOIN tableb b1
ON a.model1 = b1.model
LEFT JOIN tableb b2
ON a.model2 = b2.model
```

But, if at all possible, a chang in schema is the best option:

- Adding a new a.model column with all nonempty values of both model1 and model2 and join on it.
- Using a materialized view like:

  SELECT a.*, CASE WHEN a.model1 = '' THEN a.model2 ELSE a.model1 END AS model

  FROM tablea a
- If there are no indexes on a.model1 or a.model2 which can improve query performance, you can use the previous view as a nonmaterialized, possibly inline, view.